# How to programmatically get content type name in Drupal 8

Tags: content-type, drupal-8

I'm working on Drupal 8. And I want to get content type machine name and label. Here is my code:

```
$cont_type = node_type_get_types();
foreach ($cont_type as $key => $value) {
  $label = $value->name;
  $machine_name = $key;
}
```

Here I got an error message : `Cannot access protected property Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::$name`

Answer (score 18):

In order to get current content type:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$typeName = $node->bundle();
$typeLabel = $node->getTitle();
```

There is an alternative method.

```
$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')
```

Comment: Welcome Jose! Try to explain what your code does to make it a better answer! You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
  use Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType;
?>

<?php
  $all_content_types = NodeType::loadMultiple();
  /** @var NodeType $content_type */
  foreach ($all_content_types as $machine_name => $content_type) {
    $label = $content_type->label();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Solved using this code in template_preprocess_node()

```
$content_type = $node->type->entity->label();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$entityTypeManager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');

$types = [];
$contentTypes = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();
foreach ($contentTypes as $contentType) {
  $types[$contentType->id()] = $contentType->label();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **NodeType** class inherits the `label()` method from the **Entity** class, use that function to get the content type label. See [Entity::label](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Alabel/8).

```
$label = $value->label();
```

Answer (score -1):

use  {{ node.field_name.fieldDefinition.label }}

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

Please use the namespace

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
```

Comment: This is not an answer